I have an error while installing Swagger with Spring
I am trying to develop a project with Spring and I am trying to download "Swagger-ui" for this. But I always encounter problems. I will share the errors I get with you below and I will share my pom.xml, application.properties and application.java files with you respectively. I am using postgresql as database and I am sure that the password is correct.
    ***************************
    APPLICATION FAILED TO START
    ***************************

    Description:

    Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).

This is just one of the errors I receive. When I make some changes to it, the error can turn into this.
      ***************************
      APPLICATION FAILED TO START
      ***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.springframework.plugin.core.support.AbstractTypeAwareSupport$BeansOfTypeTargetSource.<init>(AbstractTypeAwareSupport.java:135)

The following method did not exist:

    'void org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(java.lang.Object)'

The calling method's class, org.springframework.plugin.core.support.AbstractTypeAwareSupport$BeansOfTypeTargetSource, was loaded from the following location:

    jar:file:/C:/Users/emirg/.m2/repository/org/springframework/plugin/spring-plugin-core/1.2.0.RELEASE/spring-plugin-core-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/plugin/core/support/AbstractTypeAwareSupport$BeansOfTypeTargetSource.class

The called method's class, org.springframework.util.Assert, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/C:/Users/emirg/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/6.1.12/spring-core-6.1.12.jar!/org/springframework/util/Assert.class

The called method's class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

    org.springframework.util.Assert: file:/C:/Users/emirg/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/6.1.12/spring-core-6.1.12.jar

Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains compatible versions of the classes org.springframework.plugin.core.support.AbstractTypeAwareSupport$BeansOfTypeTargetSource and org.springframework.util.Assert

MY pom.xml FİLE
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>kodlamaio</groupId>
    <artifactId>northwind</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>northwind</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <licenses>
        <license/>
    </licenses>
    <developers>
        <developer/>
    </developers>
    <scm>
        <connection/>
        <developerConnection/>
        <tag/>
        <url/>
    </scm>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>


MY application.properties PAGE
spring.application.name=northwind
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.hibernate.show-sql=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Northwind
spring.datasource.username=*****
spring.datasource.password=*****
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.validation.mode = none
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.profiles.active=dev

MY NorthwindApplication.java PAGE
package kodlamaio.northwind;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableSwagger2
public class NorthwindApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(NorthwindApplication.class, args);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public Docket api() { 
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)  
          .select()                                  
          .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("kodlamaio.northwind"))                                   
          .build();                                           
    } 

} 

MY ProductsController.java PAGE
package kodlamaio.northwind.api.controllers;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import kodlamaio.northwind.business.abstracts.ProductService;
import kodlamaio.northwind.entities.concretes.Product;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/products")
public class ProductsController {
    
    @Autowired
    public ProductsController(ProductService productService) {
        super();
        this.productService = productService;
    }

    private ProductService productService;
    
    @GetMapping("/getall")
    public List<Product> getAll(){
        return this.productService.getAll();
        
    }

}

Then I decided to try something different and decided to use openapi-ui and added the following to my pom.xml file.
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.0</version>
</dependency>

But this time I was facing the following error on the localhost:8080 port.
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Sun Sep 01 16:06:17 TRT 2024
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No static resource swagger-ui.html.
org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.NoResourceFoundException: No static resource swagger-ui.html.

I know there is a mismatch between my spring folders and the code I wrote. But I don't know how to fix it and ChatGPT didn't help at all.

Can you check this

Play one ball at a time. Test one function at a time until it can be executed. Then add a second function.

Step1: You should build a minimal Spring Boot + JPA executable example.
Step2: Add Swagger function to the project.

Minimal testable Spring Boot + JPA + Swapper Doc API example:
Project Tree
demo-jpa
├── pom.xml
└── src
    └── main
        ├── java
        │   └── com
        │       └── example
        │           ├── DemoJpaApplication.java
        │           ├── WebConfig.java                
        │           ├── HelloController.java
        │           ├── model
        │           │   └── Person.java
        │           ├── controller
        │           │   └── PersonController.java
        │           ├── repository
        │           │   └── PersonRepository.java
        │           └── service
        │               └── PersonService.java
        └── resources
            ├── application.properties
            └── data.sql

pom.xml

application.properties
spring.application.name=demo-jpa

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.sql.init.mode=always
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always


# http://localhost:8080/h2-console
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console

# swagger
springdoc.swagger-ui.path=/swagger-ui.html
springdoc.api-docs.path=/api-docs

data.sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PERSON (
    ID BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    NAME VARCHAR(255),
    MAIL VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO PERSON (NAME, MAIL) VALUES ('John Doe', 'john@example.com');
INSERT INTO PERSON (NAME, MAIL) VALUES ('Jane Doe', 'jane@example.com');

DemoJpaApplication.java
package com.example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoJpaApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoJpaApplication.class, args);
    }

}

WebConfig.java
package com.example;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.web.config.EnableSpringDataWebSupport;

@Configuration
@EnableSpringDataWebSupport(pageSerializationMode = EnableSpringDataWebSupport.PageSerializationMode.VIA_DTO)
public class WebConfig {

}

HelloController.java
NOT JPA
package com.example;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @GetMapping("/hello/{name}")
    public String sayHello(
            @PathVariable String name,
            @RequestParam(value = "greeting", defaultValue = "Hello") String greeting) {
        return String.format("%s, %s!", greeting, name);
    }
}

Person.java
package com.example.model;

import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Schema;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Schema(hidden = true)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String mail;

    // Constructors, getters, and setters
    public Person() {
    }

    public Person(String name, String mail) {
        this.name = name;
        this.mail = mail;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getMail() {
        return mail;
    }

    public void setMail(String mail) {
        this.mail = mail;
    }
}

PersonController.java
package com.example.controller;

import com.example.model.Person;
import com.example.service.PersonService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.Optional;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/persons")
public class PersonController {
    @Autowired
    private PersonService personService;

    @GetMapping
    public Page<Person> getAllPersons(@RequestParam(defaultValue = "0") int page, @RequestParam(defaultValue = "10") int size) {
        return personService.getAllPersons(page, size);
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public Optional<Person> getPersonById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return personService.getPersonById(id);
    }

    @PostMapping
    public Person createPerson(@RequestBody Person person) {
        return personService.savePerson(person);
    }

    @PutMapping("/{id}")
    public Person updatePerson(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody Person updatedPerson) {
        Optional<Person> optionalPerson = personService.getPersonById(id);
        if (optionalPerson.isPresent()) {
            Person person = optionalPerson.get();
            person.setName(updatedPerson.getName());
            person.setMail(updatedPerson.getMail());
            return personService.savePerson(person);
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Person not found");
        }
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public void deletePerson(@PathVariable Long id) {
        personService.deletePerson(id);
    }
}

PersonService.java
package com.example.service;

import com.example.model.Person;
import com.example.repository.PersonRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.Optional;

@Service
public class PersonService {
    @Autowired
    private PersonRepository personRepository;

    public Page<Person> getAllPersons(int page, int size) {
        return personRepository.findAll(PageRequest.of(page, size));
    }

    public Optional<Person> getPersonById(Long id) {
        return personRepository.findById(id);
    }

    public Person savePerson(Person person) {
        return personRepository.save(person);
    }

    public void deletePerson(Long id) {
        personRepository.deleteById(id);
    }
}

PersonRepository.java
package com.example.repository;

import com.example.model.Person;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository;

public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Long>, PagingAndSortingRepository<Person, Long> {
}

Build And Run
Build
mvn clean package

Run
java -jar target/demojpa.jar

Test Api
Open http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html

Instead using multiple dependency You can use only one dependency
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
   <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.2</version>
</dependency>

After that just try to run the command
mvn dependency:tree

And then hit url
http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html

Even you don't need to write any swagger configuration.
May be you can read more here
